# Concatenating millions of xml files in a single json file using bash

Tags: javascript, python, json, xml, bash

I would like to merge 2.5 million smallish xml files from a directory tree into one large json file, and I was trying to do this using bash using `find` and the `xml2json` utility.

I'm pretty new to bash and haven't done anything very complicated with it. My intuition is something like following (but this is a long way from working):

```
find . -exec xml2json {} ; cat >> merged.json
```

Problem #1: I can't figure out how to use the xml2json utility with `-exec`.

```
find . -exec /usr/bin/xml2json < {}
```

doesn't work (seems like it's waiting for more input?). Neither does

```
find . -exec /usr/bin/xml2json {}
```

How do I get this working?

Problem #2: What is the most efficient way to concatenate the files? Obviously just using `cat` isn't going to create a well-formed json file, but can I just concatenate in brackets at the start and end and commas in between? Or should I use something like `jq`'s `-s`? Do I need to stream it or parallelize it?

If it turns out bash is bad for this, efficient alternatives in JavaScript, R, or Python would also be useful. Thanks.

Comment: How does `xml2json` work? If you use `xml2json example.xml` does it create `example.json` in current directory or does it output json code to stdout?

Comment: You have to explicitly use the `<` and `>` operators like so: `$ xml2json < input.xml > output.json` The javascript source is [here](https://github.com/Inist-CNRS/node-xml2json-command/blob/master/xml2json.js).